# Firefox inspect: how to "trace" inline styles in Angular

Tags: css, angular

How do I find out where this rule comes from? It only has the component ngcontent attribute-selector. It says "inline:380", but when I click on this link "inline:380" to show me those inline styles the firefox inspect tools lead me to a completely unrelated stylsheet with fonts.

[image]

Maybe someone can confirm this is a bug from firefox inspect tools?

And maybe someone can tell for which possible reasons this rule gets created and how to "trace" it to its source?

The element in the elements tab:
[image]

Comment: check if style tag is applied on the element.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "style tag". Obviously this ruleset is applied on the element since its rules (margin & padding) are not striked through.

Comment: it is like `style="margin-0; padding:0;"`. check in the elements tab panel.

Comment: Oh you meant I should check whether there are inline styles in the element. No there are none. I just included a picture of the element in the elements panel/tab too.

Comment: and you can also try checking out the line number 380 in the same elements panel.

Comment: ngcontent means it is coming from Angular. Check the component file itself to see how the styles are applied to the element. I guess this is coming from the minified, production version? Finding out the exact place where something happens can be tricky and difficult there. Do this on the develop-build.